# Is there a way/tools to show all the memory mapped files in the system?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, c#-4.0, io

After creating a named memory mapped file, is there any tool under windows to show the memory mapped files?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 process explorer lists these for a process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sysinternal's [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) is a browser for the kernel object namespace.

Memory-mapped files appear as kernel objects of type "Section".

You'll need to run WinObj as an Administrator and you'll typically find your objects under "Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects".